# проверка ключей скрипта powershell

Tags: powershell

Всем доброго! Есть скрипт который принимает на вход 2 параметра типа datetime. Так же имеется ввод параметров пользователем. Как мне организовать проверку на правильность, вернее если я ввожу в ключе бред, то мне выдавало не ошибку(ты ввел не datetime тип), а оно попадало с обработку исключений. Так же если кто знает, как организовать логирование по уровням? Start-Transcript загоняет просто все а флаги -ErrorAction, -WarningAction не работают. Спасибо.

```
      param
        (
             [datetime]$sleep,
             [datetime]$wake_up
        )   
Start-Transcript .\logger.txt -Append
function do_sleep () 
{
    if (!$sleep)
    {
        [datetime]$sleep = Read-Host "Input time when you go to sleep"
    }
    if (!$wake_up)
    {
        [datetime]$wake_up = Read-Host "Input time when you wake up"
    }
    if ($wake_up.Hour -le 8 ) {
        Write-Host "You are lark"
    }
    if ($wake_up.Hour -gt 8) {
        Write-Host "You are owl"
    }
    if ($wake_up -lt $sleep) {
        $sleeping_time = ($wake_up.AddDays(1) - $sleep)
        $normal_sleep = $sleeping_time.hours;
    }
    else {
        $sleeping_time = $wake_up - $sleep;
        $normal_sleep = $sleeping_time.hours;
    }   
    if ($normal_sleep -ge 8 ) {
        Write-Host "You slept more"  $sleeping_time.Hours  "hours. You are lucky man. " 
    }
}
do
{
    try
    {
        do_sleep
        exit
    }
    catch 
    {
        Write-Host ("Wrong input. Please input data again.")
        $g = 1;
    }
}
while ($g -eq 1)
Stop-Transcript
```

Answer (score 0):

у каждого параметра можно задать атрибут `validatescript`, в котором указать скрипт выполняющий проверку. см. [About Functions Advanced Parameters](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters) или [по-русски](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh847743.aspx).